# Kernel of an evaluation homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> I have the following  evaluation-homomorphism:
>
> $$\phi: K[X,Y]  \to K[T]$$ $$X \to T^3$$ $$Y \to T^2$$
>
> I have to prove that $\ker \phi=(X^2-Y^3)$.

$\subseteq$ It is obvious as $\phi(X^2-Y^3)=0$.

$\supseteq$ Take $f(X,Y)\in \ker\phi$, is $f \in (X^2-Y^3)$?

I have divided $f$ by $X^2-Y^3$, by the indeterminate $X$. So I get $f(X,Y)=q(X,Y)(X^2-Y^3)+ p(X,Y)$ where $\deg_X p\leq1$

$(q_1(X,Y), p_1(X,Y) \in K[X,Y]$)

As $\deg_X p\leq1$, we can write $p_1(X,Y)= a(Y)X+ b(Y)$.

How can I continue?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. 
Write $a(Y)=\sum a_i Y^i$, similarly for $b$ and note what it means that $\phi(a(Y)X+b(Y))=0$.

Comment: Could you help me a little more? I can see what it means that $\phi(a(Y)X+b(y))=0$